# Missing images after grunt build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using Grunt in my project (Yeoman based), but when I try to build my app with the `grunt build` command, I have the following errors when images are loaded :

```
GET http://mydomain.com/dist/images/login_user.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I understand that they are not found after the building process because they have been minified and now they have this name :

```
3f59e511.login_user.png
```

But I can not find what to change in my bower.json file to change their name by the minified one in my app's files. Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

I used the dependency below to correct a problem I had before ( see [AngularJS Inject service in .run function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357500/angularjs-inject-service-in-run-function)

```
uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            }
        },
```

And I think the error could come from that but I don't know exactly why.

Answer (score -1):

Actually when you build your application the dist folder will be cleaned up, and grunt then will create new files using the source files that you specified in the gruntfile. So use the grunt copy dependency to move the image to the dist folder at runtime.

Comment: I was already aware about the whole process but I do not get what is exactly your solution to my problem

Comment: I think images no need to minified.